# correct usage of 'prolonged'

Tags: adjectives

Can someone tell me if usage of 'prolonged' in the following sentence is correct?

The winter season is prolonged till the first week of March.

Comment: It's contextual isn't it? In a declarative it may be valid depending on who is declaring it and if they have the power to affect the weather.

Answer (score 1):

That sentence is correct, but it may not have the meaning that you intend. It only makes sense as an administrative announcement; "the winter season" has to be something that humans control the duration of, and your sentence is stating that its duration has been lengthened by extending it to the beginning of March.

For example, this could work in a school sporting context, if there are sports that are played during "the winter season" and sports that are played during "the spring season", and the announcement is that the winter-season sports will continue for longer than originally planned.

**Edited to add:** Note that the *adjective* "prolonged", by contrast, does *not* require human action; for example, we can speak of "a prolonged drought". But in the sentence that you quote, I think the construction "is prolonged till […]" only makes sense as the passive voice, meaning that it's using the *verb* "prolong". This, and the use of the present tense, are why it only makes sense as an administrative announcement.

Comment: I don't agree. It is *mostly* used for something which can be changed by human intervention (not necessarily in an administrative announcement) e.g. *They prolonged the meeting in order to debate the demolition of the town hall*.  But there is also no reason at all why it cannot be applied to natural events e.g. *We have been enjoying a  prolonged summer, with high temperatures well into October*.

Comment: So how about this? In city x,one can enjoy prolonged winter season  till first week of March

Comment: @WS2: I'm not saying that the adjective "prolonged" requires human action; the phrase "a prolonged drought", for example, is extremely well attested. But in the OP's sentence, I don't think we can interpret "prolonged" as a participial adjective; rather, "is prolonged till [...]" can only be interpreted as the passive voice. And given the use of the present tense, it only makes sense as an administrative announcement.

Comment: @ruakh I see your point. But I think you need to make your answer a bit clearer - perhaps by including the text of your comment.

Comment: @WS2: Fair enough; done.

Comment: @user128849: That example doesn't work, because if the city's winters *always* last till March, then it's not really "prolonged".